# How to convert simple array to object in php

Tags: php, arrays

i am new in PHP array, i have array an it is simple array

```
<?php array("key"=>"value" , "key1"=>"value1"); ?>
```

i need to convert it in std object array like follow

```
array(
stdClass Object
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [key] => value 
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [key1] => value1
        )
);
```

Comment: `$object = (object) $array; //$question.close();`

Comment: function convertToObject($array) {
    $object = new stdClass();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $value = convertToObject($value);
        }
        $object->$key = $value;
    }
    return $object;
}